# minimal set of correspondences for Essential matrix given intrinsics?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Fundamental matrix requires 8 correspondences. How many image-image correspondences are required for estimating essential matrix, given intrinsics and why? Since essential matrix is made out of Rotation and Translation, 3+2(translation is only upto a scale) there are 5 parameters that needs to be estimated, each correspondence gives one equation. Does it mean 5 correspondences are enough to estimate a essential matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Five point correspondences are enough to estimate the Essential Matrix. D. Nister provided an efficient solver back in 2004, immediately followed by a somewhat more elegant one by E. Stewenius. The Nister solver is the one used by the OpenCv "findEssentialMat" routine.

However, you have your math a bit wrong: 5 point correspondences in general position provide 10 linear constraints. If there were no ambiguities in the projection, a minimal solver would need 3 point correspondences.